# Connecting MQ7.X over SSL using java

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

We need to connect to MQ over SSL by using java standalone program. We have received `.arm` file from the Partner and we have installed the certificate using `keytool` command as given below:

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/keytool -import -alias my_cert -file mycert.arm -keystore /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Enter keystore password:
---
---
----
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

Program to connect Queue Manager in java

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
MQEnvironment.channel = "Channel_Name"; // With  SSL
MQEnvironment.port = XXXX;

System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustpass");
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA";

_queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QueueManagerName");

System.out.println("\t _queueManager                        : " + _queueManager);
```

Error getting as given below

```
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is :
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
MQJE013: Error accessing socket streams
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
MQJE013: Error accessing socket streams
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
MQJE013: Error accessing socket streams
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:212)
```

Can you please help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013804170) *Reason 2059* relates to a non-running listener service.

> Figured out the problem. There is a "HTTP SSL" service, which apparently needs to be running. When the box was rebooted, it wasn't started. Starting the service, and re-starting the WAS server fixed the problem.